# No module named MuSQLdb(Running with sudo)

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, dht

I'm using Raspbian, Python 3 and MySQL.
So my code runs normal if I just click "Run" in Python 3, but if I open Terminal and type `sudo python mycode.py` I get an error saying

> ImportError: No module named MySQLdb

, but just if I run that way.

The thing is that I add recently a DHT11 to my project and I need to import Adafruit_DHT to my code, but I get the error

> "No module named Adafruit_DHT"

if I run my code normal and I can run normal if I run with sudo in terminal. So how can I solve first problem? ("no module named mysql").

PS: I need both modules in the same code.

PS2: Pardon me for my English.

Comment: Was MySQLdb installed with pip/in a virtual env?  If so the sudo will eliminate the environment variables python uses to find its modules.

Comment: PS, English is fine. Only the typo in the title makes it look like and obvious fault. No need to apologize for language.

Comment: If you just do `sudo python`, which version of Python is launched?

Comment: I found a solution. First, I didn't know if I installed  MySQLdb with pip/in a virtual env because I installed a long time ago. So I typed `sudo python`. I saw that by defaut it was running Python 2.7.13 and to solve my problem, I  just installed adafruit in Python 3 with `sudo pip3 install Adafruit_DHT`.


Thanks for helping me guys :).